# NFC-V write tag + onClickListener

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

I would like to write data on the tag (ISO 15963) after the button is clicked. I can write data on the tag when activity is open. I just don't know how to do the application start to cooperate with tag after click button. Is there any way to do this without calling a new activity? Thank you a lot!

CODE:

```
public class WrBlock extends Activity {

private Button wbutton;
private NfcAdapter myNfcAdapter;
private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
private String[][] mTechLists;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blockw);

    wbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    myNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter intnfcv = new IntentFilter(
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { intnfcv, };
    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcV.class.getName() },
            new String[] { NdefFormatable.class.getName() } };

    wbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // HERE I WANT TO WRITE DATA

        }
    });
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
    setIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent()
                .getAction())) {
            Tag tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            showMessage(null, "Technologies available in this tag="
                    + Arrays.toString(tag.getTechList()));
            Tag detectedTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
                    NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            NfcV nfcv = NfcV.get(detectedTag);
            try {
                nfcv.connect();
                if (nfcv.isConnected()) {
                    showMessage(null, "Connected to the tag");
                    showMessage(null,
                            "\nTag DSF: " + Byte.toString(nfcv.getDsfId()));
                    byte[] buffer;
                    buffer = nfcv.transceive(new byte[] {0x00, 0x21, (byte) 0,0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31});
                    showMessage(null, "\nByte block 10:" + buffer);

                    nfcv.close();
                    wrmode = false;
                    showMessage(null, "Successfully writing");
                } else
                    showMessage(null, "Not connected to the tag");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage(null, "Error");
                wrmode = false;
            }
        } else {
            showMessage(null, "ELSE ");
            wrmode = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (myNfcAdapter != null) {
        myNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent,
                mFilters, mTechLists);
    }
}

    public void showMessage(View v, CharSequence x) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: When designing your application like this, you should keep in mind that both, tapping the NFC tag and clicking the button are UI events. Therefore, with your approach, the user would first need to tap the tag **and keep the tag in reach of the phone** and **at the same time** touch the button on the screen. Typically, you would let the user click the button **first** and **then wait** until the tag is tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the Tag in a field of the Activity. Doing this  you can execute the logic of tag operations when the button is clicked. With these modifications, it should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Tag mTag;
    private IntentFilter[] mFilters;
    private String[][] mTechLists;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private Button wbutton;
    private NfcAdapter myNfcAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                writeTag(mTag);
            }
        });
        configureNfc();
    }

    private void configureNfc(){
        myNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter intnfcv = new IntentFilter(
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { 
                intnfcv};
        mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] {
                NfcV.class.getName() }};
    }

    private synchronized void writeTag(Tag tag){
        if(mTag !=null){
            try {
                new WriteVecinityTagTask().execute().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mTag=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (myNfcAdapter != null) {
            myNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent,
                    mFilters, mTechLists);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
        setIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            mTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }

    private class WriteVecinityTagTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String message = (result) ? "WRITE OK" : "ERROR";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                NfcV vecinityTag = NfcV.get(mTag);
                vecinityTag.connect();
                vecinityTag.transceive(
                        new byte[] {0x00, 0x21, (byte) 0,0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31}
                        );
                vecinityTag.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm little confused about use this code for write data to the tag. I think I can write data to the tag only with **nfcv.transceive** beacuse my tag is from **nfcV class.**

Comment: Now the code looks really good but I have the same problem like before because everytime inside onClick vecinityTag.isConnected() - is not connected.

Comment: mTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG); needs be just like this. Now it works. Thank you.